# Card IO Android SDK clashes with Braintree Android SDK?

Tags: android, braintree, card.io

Hi I am just trying to use the [Card IO](https://www.card.io/) and [Braintree Android SDK](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/android+ruby/) in one Android Project using Android Studio with Gradle build of course. I haven't even add any code referencing these 2 libraries yet. I just set them as dependency in the gradle build file as shown below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "blahblahblah"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ......
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':android-async-http-1.4.6')
    compile project(':gson-2.3.1')
    compile project(':card.io')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+'
}
```

Then I tried a clean and build which succeed but when I try to run it on the testing phone i received the following :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Applications/ADT_Bundle/sdk/build-tools/21.1.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /path_to_project_root/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/path_to_project_root/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt

```
Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lio/card/payment/b;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

I tried deleting everything under

> app/build/generated, outputs and temp

and even invalid Android Studio cache and restart. No good. What this looks like to me is that something that both Card IO and Braintree Android SDK has and they both are about to be packed into the apk. Does Braintree Android SDK included Card IO already or something ?

Can anyone point out where I did wrong ? Many many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Braintree SDK already includes the cardio java classes.  However, it does not include the .so files.  Please try removing your local copy of card.io.jar, and everything should work.

Comment: Thank you very much Jeff. Maybe a note on Github or the homepage about this would stop quite a few suicides (well, suicide of less intelligent but hard-working coders)

Comment: We plan on removing card.io from within the Braintree sdk, and will update the build instructions accordingly when that happens.

Comment: It is mentioned in [DEVELOPMENT.md](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/blob/2c570fcc469613e903a81f8b2892083fdf4ebffa/DEVELOPMENT.md#environmental-assumptions), however it is a bit buried.

Answer (score 3):

With release 1.3.0, the Braintree SDK no longer includes a copy of card.io.